# onActivityResult method from different class for picking image from gallery

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

I am developing an Android E-commerce Application. I am implementing an Admin module. I have done the insertion of data. Now, I moved to the update of data. Now I implemented a RecyclerView to view data from firebase like image (i.e product image), text, etc. when I long press on recycler view, here I display a dialog box for getting new data that is to be updated. There I passed a chosen button that can select image from the gallery. and add it into firebase again. But i am getting problem that is i cannot be able to override onActivityResult in custom dialog box class. Please provide me a solution. 
This is my dialog box choose button.

```
chose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity A = (Activity) mcontext;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            A.startActivityForResult(intent, Image_Request_Code);
            ViewProducts vi = new ViewProducts();

            vi.onActivityResult(Image_Request_Code, A.RESULT_OK, intent, imageView1);

        }
    });
```

This is my onActivityResult that is in Viewproducts class.

```
public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data , ImageView image){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        FilePathUri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri)) ;

}
```

Comment: `vi.onActivityResult(Image_Request_Code. ). `Remove that. You are not supposed to call onActivityResult yourself.

Comment: The onActivityResult of your Activity will be called after the user selected and image. Use that one.

Comment: What kind of class is ViewProducts?

Comment: view products is the class where i am showing data from my firebase using recycler view.

Comment: Not precise enough. Did you extend it from another class? ( Dont only say yes if you did).